# How to get current date and time in php

Tags: php, date, datetime

Thanks in advance. Actually i was using  `date('Y-m-d h:i:s', time())` and `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` to get the current date and time in php but it's not showing the proper time. Instead of showing proper Indian time it's showing some other time 
My code is:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo "Current date and time is ".$today;
```

Comment: check your server timezone?

Comment: Use date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta'); //India

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); 
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // time in India
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, use date_default_timezone_set (Asia/Kolkata)

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo "Current date and time is ".$today;
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/673267)**

Answer (score 2):

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo "Current date and time is ".$today;
```

This will help you to find your location: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) for set the specific time zone as:

```
if (function_exists('date_default_timezone_set'))
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Mumbai'); // will set the mumbai timezone.
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

*This will help you to find your location: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php*

**[Demo](https://eval.in/673272)**

Comment: What is cause of using `function_exists()` while `date_default_timezone_set()` function added in php 5 at 10 years ago?

Comment: @Mohammad: nothing special for this function bcoz its available in all php version 5+, it's just a good approach to use this... but nothing special here..

Comment: @RagithThomas: glad to help u

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) for set Indian time:

```
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); //Indian time.
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```